# get page by page name in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am developing a cms. I am facing a problem regarding htaccess. I want the url like this

```
Old: http://example.com/detail.php?name=xyz
New: http://www.example.com/xyz
```

Currently , I am using this rule

```
RewriteRule -(.*)/?$ detail.php?detail=$1
```

but as I removes the dash from rule ,it does not works. here is php code for link

```
<?php $menu_block .= "<li><a href='-$newName'>".$row['pd_name']."</a>"; ?>
```

and in detail.php page , I am getting page name like this

```
$this_id = $_GET['detail'];
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. What do you mean by "as I removes the dash from rule"? What does "it does not works" mean exactly?

Comment: In htaccess, I am using -(.*)/? detail/php?detail$1. So if I donot type dash/hyphene or minus sign before ( , the page does not loads.

Comment: So you mean it removes from the argument you want to capture, not from the rule? The trailing `/` is optional because of the `?` following it. Indeed it is not part of `$1`, but I doubt that is what you want. So leaving it away won't make the rule stop working. About the dash leading the rule: what is the idea behind that? I don't understand the intention, why don't you simply remove it? Or maybe you wanted to type a `^` instead?

Comment: dear, would you please simply tell me how can i get the this type of url

Old: http://example.com/detail.php?name=xyz
New: http://www.example.com/xyz

I am calling/getting database entry by name not ID

Comment: That is a bit difficult without you answering to questions :-) But I gave it a try below :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without any more specific details from your side all we can do is *guess* what you are looking for...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ detail.php?detail=$1
```

And probably this is how to create the references:

```
<?php $menu_block .= "<li><a href='$newName'>".$row['pd_name']."</a>"; ?>
```

Sorry if this is vague. I am aware of that. But unfortunately your question is somewhat unclear...

---

Note that the above is the syntax for usage within `.htaccess` style files. For usage inside the host configuration (which is preferable) the syntax would have to be adjusted slightly to also consider the leading slash of the path component.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I tried this but it is not working. Now I think I can clear my question. As you added a cap character ^ before this rule, I am adding - character instead of this. If I donot use it, page does not loads. I think there must be some string/character. and same character I am using in php file as <a href='-$newName'>".$row['pd_name']."</a>

Comment: Sorry, no, your conclusion is simply wrong. The `^` has a special meaning in regular expressions (take a look at the documentation please). You do _not_ need some fixed leading character in references to be able to rewrite them. Obviously you _can_ do so, but it is neither required nor does it make sense. The `^` only expresses "no character before what comes now". It "anchors" the expression to the line beginning.

Comment: Thank you arkascha....I think I am unable to clear the question...But Thankyou so much...

Comment: I suggest you use the rule I posted above and try manually by changing your browsers URL bar. So leave away php for the moment. To find out how that rewriting works. Then php comes in as a second step. And I can only repeat: _take a look at the documentation!_ It is well worth reading. Very precise and clear and it offers good examples. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html